# How to get the height of table in dynamic-report Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am wonder how to get the height of a table by using a dynamic report to set my page height exactly to fit the ( table height ) .
so, **the height of page = the height of table**

```
 private void build() {
    try {
        JasperReportBuilder report = report()
                .columns(
                        col.column("Qty", "qty", type.integerType()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.LEFT).setFixedWidth(25),
                        col.column("Item", "item", type.stringType()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.LEFT),
                        col.column("UP", "price", type.bigDecimalType()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.LEFT).setFixedWidth(30),
                        col.column("Sub", "sub", type.bigDecimalType()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.LEFT).setFixedWidth(30)
                )

                .setDataSource(createDataSource())
                .setPageFormat(200,???,  PageOrientation.PORTRAIT) // width , height               
                .show() ;


    } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private JRDataSource createDataSource() {
    DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("qty" , "item" ,"price", "sub");
    dataSource.add(4,"Book" ,new BigDecimal("33"), new BigDecimal("33"));
    dataSource.add(6,"CD", new BigDecimal("33"),new BigDecimal("24"));

    return dataSource;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought I can work around problem by no of data* row size
but the row size can be different if and just if there is too much characters which can not fit the width so it move to the second line and so on 
Do you have any alternative solution

Comment: Try to do .setIgnorePagination(true) on the report.

Comment: This works thank you for your help @dada67

Comment: @dada67 but still I need to set the height of the page ?
I can set a height very large and use .setIgnorePagination(true)
but is there any other way ?

Comment: Yes, you still need to set a page height.  I don't know any other solutions.